# How to load other view when loaded notifications?

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm using Xcode 4.5.1

I need the anwser how to load other view? when loaded nofications..

I coded program using Local Notifications.

This program can alert When application is lying background.

How can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to reload the view when the application is "opened" from the notification ?

Comment: Please can you provide some code to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the notification about the UILocalNotification in two places depending on app's state at the time the notification is fired.

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, if the app is neither running nor in the background.

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
  if (localNotif) {
      // open your custom view here 
  }
  ...
  }